# Is There A Way To Add Icons or Components to Custom Labels?

Tags: customlabel, lightning-app-builder

Specifically something like lightning help text? And even more specifically for use in a lightning app designer standard tab component tab label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cl_about.htm&type=5),

> Custom labels are custom text values

so it is not possible.